# Java generic class to accept only specific class type?

Tags: java

I am using JAVA7. I need to write class using generics which will act on specific class. How can i write?

Class name : `SomeClass.java`
It should accept only class types of `SomeOtherClass.java`.

Can i write as below?

```
public class SomeClass<SomeOtherClass> {


}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the only valid parameter is `SomeOtherClass` why use generics at all? Just use that class directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "accept" only one class type? From the question I surmise that you don't know exactly what generics do.

```
public class SomeClass<T> {
    private T it;

    public T getIt() {
        return it;
    }

    public void setIt(T it) {
        this.it = it;
    }
}

public static void main(String...args) {
    SomeClass<String> someClass = new SomeClass<String>();
    someClass.setIt("this is it!");
    System.out.println(someClass.getIt());
}
```

The generics in this example allow you (the developer writing the main method) to specify what type T is which makes your code cleaner and safer as the compiler can check that you are indeed using the type you defined. If you would try:

```
someClass.setIt(5);
```

This would give a compiler error because you defined it as a String.

In that respect there is no point at all to defining only a specific class. What you **could** do is this:

```
public class SomeClass<T extends SomeOtherClass>
```

Which enables you to say that the developer must define T to be an extension of SomeOtherClass. This means that when using T inside SomeClass, you (and the compiler) can assume that it is at least of type SomeOtherClass and use any methods available there.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot write as you've shown. Your notation declares a new type variable called `SomeOtherClass`. It has no relation to the type `SomeOtherClass`.

Instead declare a type variable and give it a bound

```
public class SomeClass<T extends SomeOtherClass> {
```

Now the type variable `T` has an upper bound of `SomeOtherClass`.

This means that parameterized uses of the `SomeClass` type must provide a type argument that is `SomeOtherClass` or any of its subtypes.